# Some tensor manipulations in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, yolo

I've been stuck for several hours on some tensor manipulations in Tensorflow. I'm trying to implement some loss function within the Keras framework using Tensorflow backend, but was unsuccessful so far (though I believe I'm getting closer). The loss function in question is that of the loss function of *YOLO* algorithm. The problem with this function, is that it is a $L_2$ norm but weighted by some coefficients depending on the value of $y_true$. Therefore, in order to build my loss function, I have to look into the value of $y_true$, **which Tensorflow seems not to allow**... Anyway, so far, I've come up with this trick:

```
def defineMarkUp(y_true):
    num_example = y_true.shape[0]
    grid_h, grid_w = config.GRID_H, config.GRID_W
    box_nbr = config.BOX_NBR
    class_nbr = config.CLASS_NBR
    coord_c = config.COORD_C
    noobj_c = config.NOOBJ_C
    s = 5 + class_nbr

    mask = np.zeros(y_true.shape)

    for i in range(num_example):
        for j in range(grid_h):
            for k in range(grid_w):
                for l in range(box_nbr):
                    if np.sum(y_true[i, j, k, l * s + 5 : (l + 1) * s]) > 0:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s : l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(coord_c)
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4 : (l + 1) * s] = 1.0
                    else:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(noobj_c)

    return mask



def yoloLoss(markups):
    grid_h, grid_w = config.GRID_H, config.GRID_W
    box_nbr = config.BOX_NBR
    class_nbr = config.CLASS_NBR
    s = 5 + class_nbr

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        mask = np.zeros((1,  grid_h, grid_w, box_nbr * s))
        mask = mask.astype(np.float32)
        for k in range(box_nbr):
            mask[:, :, :, k * s + 2 : k * s + 4] = 1.0
        dim_y_true = tf.sqrt(tf.multiply(y_true, mask))
        dim_y_pred = tf.sqrt(tf.multiply(y_pred, mask))

        other_y_true = tf.multiply(y_true, 1 - mask)
        other_y_pred = tf.multiply(y_pred, 1 - mask)

        new_y_true = other_y_true + dim_y_true 
        new_y_pred = other_y_pred + dim_y_pred

        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.multiply(tf.cast(markups, tf.float32), (new_y_true - new_y_pred))))

    return loss
```

A little bit of explanation : here, the function defineMarkUp look at **the all labels as np.array** and create some masks (contains the different weights depending on the position etc...), and then I call something like:

```
model.compile(loss = [yoloLoss(Y_train)], optimizer = 'adadelta')
```

The problem is, when using **batch**, since the all dataset does not have the same dimension as our batch, the mask doesn't fit anymore, meaning I need to build 'markups' on the fly given **$y_true$ as a tensor**. So I tried something like this:

```
def defineMarkUp(y_true):
    num_example = y_true.get_shape().as_list()[0]
    grid_h, grid_w = config.GRID_H, config.GRID_W
    box_nbr = config.BOX_NBR
    class_nbr = config.CLASS_NBR
    coord_c = config.COORD_C
    noobj_c = config.NOOBJ_C
    s = 5 + class_nbr

    mask = np.zeros(y_true.get_shape().as_list())

    for i in range(num_example):
        for j in range(grid_h):
            for k in range(grid_w):
                for l in range(box_nbr):
                    if np.sum(y_true[i, j, k, l * s + 5 : (l + 1) * s]) > 0:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s : l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(coord_c)
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4 : (l + 1) * s] = 1.0
                    else:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(noobj_c)

    return mask

def yoloLossFinal(y_true, y_pred):
    grid_h, grid_w = config.GRID_H, config.GRID_W
    box_nbr = config.BOX_NBR
    class_nbr = config.CLASS_NBR
    s = 5 + class_nbr
    coord_c, noobj_c = config.COORD_C, config.NOOBJ_C

    markups = defineMarkUp(y_true)

    mask = np.zeros((1,  grid_h, grid_w, box_nbr * s))
    mask = mask.astype(np.float32)

    for k in range(box_nbr):
        mask[:, :, :, k * s + 2 : k * s + 4] = 1.0

    dim_y_true = tf.sqrt(tf.multiply(y_true, mask))
    dim_y_pred = tf.sqrt(tf.multiply(y_pred, mask))

    other_y_true = tf.multiply(y_true, 1 - mask)
    other_y_pred = tf.multiply(y_pred, 1 - mask)

    new_y_true = other_y_true + dim_y_true 
    new_y_pred = other_y_pred + dim_y_pred

    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.multiply(tf.cast(markups, tf.float32), (new_y_true - new_y_pred))))
```

But now I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "network.py", line 214, in
>   
>       yolo.compile(loss = yoloLossFinal, optimizer = 'adadelta')   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 830, in compile
>       sample_weight, mask)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 429, in weighted
>       score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)   File "network.py", line 192, in yoloLossFinal
>       markups = defineMarkUp(y_true)   File "network.py", line 143, in defineMarkUp
>       mask = np.zeros(y_true.get_shape().as_list()) TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Therefore, I tried something else :

```
def defineMarkUp(y_true):
    sess = tf.Session()
    with sess.as_default():
        yy = y_true.eval()

    num_example = yy.shape[0]
    grid_h, grid_w = config.GRID_H, config.GRID_W
    box_nbr = config.BOX_NBR
    class_nbr = config.CLASS_NBR
    coord_c = config.COORD_C
    noobj_c = config.NOOBJ_C
    s = 5 + class_nbr

    mask = np.zeros(y_true.shape)

    for i in range(num_example):
        for j in range(grid_h):
            for k in range(grid_w):
                for l in range(box_nbr):
                    if np.sum(yy[i, j, k, l * s + 5 : (l + 1) * s]) > 0:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s : l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(coord_c)
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4 : (l + 1) * s] = 1.0
                    else:
                        mask[i, j, k, l * s + 4] = np.sqrt(noobj_c)

    return mask
```

But now I get this very long error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1322, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1307, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_4_target' with dtype float
>   and shape [?,?,?,?]    [[Node: conv2d_4_target =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?,?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "network.py", line 218, in
>   
>       yolo.compile(loss = yoloLossFinal, optimizer = 'adadelta')   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 830, in compile
>       sample_weight, mask)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 429, in weighted
>       score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)   File "network.py", line 196, in yoloLossFinal
>       markups = defineMarkUp(y_true)   File "network.py", line 137, in defineMarkUp
>       yy = y_true.eval()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 710, in eval
>       return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 5180, in _eval_using_default_session
>       return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 900, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1135, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1316, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1335, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must
>   feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_4_target' with dtype float
>   and shape [?,?,?,?]    [[Node: conv2d_4_target =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?,?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'conv2d_4_target', defined at:   File "network.py", line
>   218, in 
>       yolo.compile(loss = yoloLossFinal, optimizer = 'adadelta')   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 725, in compile
>       dtype=K.dtype(self.outputs[i]))   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 508, in placeholder
>       x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 1808, in placeholder
>       return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 4848, in placeholder
>       "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 787, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3392, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1718, in **init**
>       self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_4_target' with dtype float and shape
>   [?,?,?,?]      [[Node: conv2d_4_target = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT,
>   shape=[?,?,?,?],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]

]

I've relentlessly trying to implement this loss function, so I really hope somebody could help me understanding what's going wrong :(. So far, I also have a more general question, that of which is probably linked to my problem: **how to really implement a loss function in Tensorflow, meaning : what are we allowed to do and what are we not allowed to do**?

*Thank you a lot!*