# On Keras and batch ground truth.

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement some loss function into Keras with Tensorflow backend. The said function being kind of tricky, I would like to come up with the following scheme:

- Through the all network, I would like to keep some information I(B) depending on the passed batch B from the input. I know this can be done by using a multi-input /output network.
- More precisely, for each batch B, I would like to retrieve the labels B_true associated, because my function I is a function of this ground truth, i.e. I(B_true)

Is this possible?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mitiku I've been trying for a whole week a lot of different stuffs. Yesterday I posted this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246475/some-tensor-manipulations-in-tensorflow, and today I'm trying something else. My question is really just about implementation, and can be stated as : how can I fetch my batch ground truth, symbolically. So I've tried a lot so far ;), I just need some help.